Receiving different output from terminal commands and script commands
When running the "cat" command without any arguments, the shell halts until I use ^C to return to command prompt.
The same happens when I run the command via a script named cat.sh.
#!/bin/bash
cat

However, when I attempt to run the script the following way, the command is successful and I don't need to hit ^C:
cat cat.sh | bash

What is the reason for this behavior?
Below is an image displaying behavior in terminal.

I am using a VM with Ubuntu Server 22.04


When running the "cat" command without any arguments, the shell halts until I use ^C to return to command prompt.

The shell doesn't halt; it has successfully run cat and is waiting for it to exit.
When run without any input files, cat will read from stdin (standard input) inherited from its parent process. In the first example (both when run directly and via cat.sh), the stdin of cat is inherited from the interactive shell, so it's connected to the terminal.
That is, cat only appears to hang but it's actually reading from your keyboard until EOF (which is a Ctrl-D either at the start of a line or following another Ctrl-D) … or until terminated by Ctrl-C.

However, when I attempt to run the script the following way, the command is successful and I don't need to hit ^C:

In the second example, the 2nd cat that is run by |bash also inherits stdin from its parent – but in this case the stdin of that 'bash' process is a pipe (receiving data from the 1st cat cat.sh), so the 2nd cat also reads from the same pipe. (All data has already been read by bash and there's nothing left for cat to read.)

This answer is meant to further clarify beyond the answer posted by grawity_u1686. This can be done by changing the cat.sh command to be the following.
#!/bin/bash
echo 'This comes before the "cat" line'
cat
echo 'This comes after the "cat" line'

Below is the output when executing the commands given in the question.
user20server:~/temp$ cat
^C
user20server:~/temp$ cat cat.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'This comes before the "cat" line'
cat
echo 'This comes after the "cat" line'
user20server:~/temp$ cat cat.sh | bash
This comes before the "cat" line
echo 'This comes after the "cat" line'
user20server:~/temp$ ./cat.sh
This comes before the "cat" line
^C
user20server:~/temp$ 

Below explains the output from executing cat cat.sh | bash.
The following completes after the contents of cat.sh starts being written to the pipe.

The first line read from the pipe instructs that bash should be used. This line is shown below.
#!/bin/bash


bash reads and executes the second line from the pipe. This line is shown below. This outputs This comes before the "cat" line.
echo 'This comes before the "cat" line'


bash read and executes the third line from the pipe. This line is shown below. The cat command reads the remaining contents of the pipe. This outputs echo 'This comes after the "cat" line'.
cat


Since the pipe is now empty, cat completes followed by bash completing.


Below are two examples where the cat.sh script was provided input for the cat command and therefore user input was not required.
user20server:~/temp$ echo 'This is the output from the "cat" line.' | ./cat.sh
This comes before the "cat" line
This is the output from the "cat" line.
This comes after the "cat" line
user20server:~/temp$ ./cat.sh <<< 'This is the output from the "cat" line.'
This comes before the "cat" line
This is the output from the "cat" line.
This comes after the "cat" line
user20server:~/temp$ 

